# PHP Mail function sends same mail twice to Gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail

I have a slightly annoying problem : my gmail account receives a mail sent by the php mail function twice. When I use different emails the mail is only received once (hotmail, own domain). I guess the problem lays in my header code.

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$naammail.' <'.$afzender.'>' . "\r\n";
```

`$naammail` is the name of the mailer and `$afzender` is the sender email.

The mail function: `mail($email,$onderwerp,$bericht,$headers);`

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you elaborate `When I use different emails the mail is only received once`? Where is the `To:` field?

Comment: I let the user type in their email. When I test with a hotmail account the whole script only runs once. The to field is there - the email the user typed in.

Answer (score 0):

```
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Make sure you use this correct. The email should go to only email address stored in $email. Use the above code and use proper names for variables. It helps to distinguish the problem (if any) easily.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I need to just pass **blank** to the 1st parameter as I already has the email address TO field in the **$headers** parameter.

```
mail( "", $subject, $message, $headers);
```